# Change local time on XP box - local admin but group policy restricts time change

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, security-policy

I am a developer in need of doing some temporal unit testing on my local XP box. I am local admin but there is a group policy enforced centrally that prohibits changing local time (a severe case of managment treating in-house devs same as every other user in the company).

I wonder if there is a way to bypass the group policy using my admin privileges and get the job done.

Comment: Roll out a VM and test it within the VM ?

Comment: If your local profile is stored on the machine, you could try pulling the network cable and restart (just log on locally).